# Using a ALSA PCM as an input device for Chromium?

Tags: audio, alsa, pcm

I have a *Matrix Creator* which I want to use as an input for a speech to text platform, running through Chromium (using *webkitSpeechRecognition*). My problem is that I do not have it available as a device, or rather that all devices I can choose courtesy of the *Creator* are not working (the sound is just scrambled). But I do have access to the raw PCM, and I was able to successfully use it with Snowboy.

Now, is there any way I can make this ALSA PCM available to Chromium as an input device? Surely there must be some way to do this using the config, but as of yet I have been unable to do this.

The PCMs are defined in `/etc/asound.conf` like this:

```
pcm.mic_channel0 {
    type file
    file "/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_0"
    infile "/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_0"
    format "raw"
    slave {
        pcm sc
    }
}
```

The device itself is working, as I can take raw input from it and play it - but I can't select it as a microphone in Chromium.

Thank you!

Comment: Reading from a file does not have the right speed. Anyway, try the `snd-aloop` driver.

Comment: @CL. Sadly it's the only way I can access it - and it does indeed work for recording, so it might work as a device? Anyways, do you have a resource how I would use the `snd-aloop` driver in this case? I looked at the wiki page, but did not see anything that really fits my use case.